# merging and sorting in Java in a more efficient way

Tags: java, sorting, merge, arrays

So, I'm trying to do this exercise for Java. I have to fill in the code and write a more efficient way of merging and sorting. The problem is, I don't completely get the concept of coding merging and sorting. I mean, I get the arrays splitting up into smaller arrays and then comparing numbers in of themselves. But I can't implement it properly. Here is the exercise instructions:

```
  public class MainClass
{
  public static void mergeSort( int[] a, int low, int high )
  {
```

Here is what I can edit:

```
    if ( low == high )
      return;

    int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

    mergeSort( a, low, mid ); 
    mergeSort( a, mid + 1, high ); 

    merge( a, low, mid, high );
  }

 public static void merge( int[] a, int low, int mid, int high )

{

  int[] temp = new int[ high - low + 1 ];



  int i = low, j = mid + 1, n = 0;



  while ( i <= mid || j <= high )

  {

    if ( i > mid )

     {

      temp[ n ] = a[ j ];

      j++;

    }

    else if ( j > high )

    {

  // write code here

    }

    else if ( a[ i ] < a[ j ] )

    {

      // write code here

    }

    else

    {

      // write code here

    }

    n++;

  }



  for ( int k = low ; k <= high ; k++ )

    a[ k ] = temp[ k - low ];

 }
```

And after that I can't edit the rest of the code:

```
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[ 25 ];

    System.out.print( "Before: " );
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
    {
       array[ i ] = r.nextInt( 125 ) - 25;
       System.out.print( array[ i ] + " " );
    }

    mergeSort( array, 0, array.length - 1 );

    System.out.print( "\n After: " );
    for ( int t : array )
      System.out.print( t + " " );
  }
}
```

So, I need a general idea of what I have to fill in where it says my code goes. What do I have to do conceptually. Examples of code are good though, but I don't want the work done for me. I want to be able to figure it out.

Thx, Sarah

Comment: If you are specifically looking for efficiency; my tip for you is to stop recursion when (high - low) < THRESHOLD and do some O(n^2) sorting after that point.